# Scala generic function fill type dynamicaly

Tags: scala, json4s

I am using a org.json4s for json read and write.
The library containa method like this.

```
val ser = read[ContentObject](jsonString)
```

But,, i want to do something like.

```
val c = Class.forName(r.e)
val e = read[Login](URLDecoder.decode(r.c))
```

Because the object type and content is retrieve in a format of String.
But this is not allow.

I would like to ask what is the right way to do this?
The method write[T], what is T? Is it a Class[]??

Thank :D

Comment: Can you add the content of JSON string and more explanation of what you want to do?

Comment: Actually I get a String "hk.jeff.Login" and try to use read[Login](...). But I dont want to hard code Login into []. But with the string.